# search for shapes in BMP image file

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an image processing question, using C#.

Say I have some schematic diagrams in BMP format, the diagram contains component shapes which are connected to each other.

I wrote a simple program to detect square shapes in the diagram as one component, and record the location of it. However, the next level is to detect more complicated shapes like a few arcs joined together. Note that these shapes can be different sizes in the image. Does anyone know any good method of doing it? without downloading any library (this is my limitation now).

After detecting the shapes, I also need to record which shape is connected to which, so later on, I can redraw them. I have one week to do this, so thanks a lot for any help!!

I'm using C#.

Comment: are your shapes rotated in the image? are they scaled?

Comment: I'd suggest you lift your limitation and take a look at OpenCV or other similar library. For my computer science degree I've taken a class in computer vision and even after that whole class one wouldn't have enough knowledge to code what you are asking for.  Leave algorithms to the science/research guys and focus on creating apps.

Comment: You have one week to do this?  Is this homework?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, the reason I am not using EmguCV or OpenCV is that I need to download their libraries, and I am limited to do so for now. I wrote an algorithm to detect squares in the image and successfully found it in 1 day time, so I think someone out there probably know lots of good methods of finding shapes, and could lend me a hand since I don't have much time to make this work. I am still a student.

Comment: The shapes can be rotated 90 or 45 degrees, that's it. They can have different size in multiple images, but in the same image, they are about the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer an old post I had, I have done what I needed to do in 2 weeks time, it worked well. I actually ended up using different algorithms for different shapes. The algorithms are a bit self inventions, but a good method I want to mention is that get the histogram and then use projection on different axis helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this paper](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/lapis/projects/udsi/aaai04.pdf).  My understanding of their approach:

- Detect edges
- Detect corners by looking for perpendicular edges
- Detect polygons by looking for groups of corners
- Detect circles using Hough transform

This is a fairly difficult research problem.  Even with a powerful computer vision library like OpenCV, implementing an effective solution within 1 week would be a demanding task.

Comment: Thank you so much misha, I think the paper you give is something very similar to what I want, except the shapes I have in the image are much neater since they are machine drawings in the first place.
I think I can skip the smoothing step, I'm not sure what the segmentation step do thou. I am more interested in finding arcs, lines, arrow etc shapes. I am a bit hesitated in using filters, since it takes times for the machine to run all the algorithms, and I probably don't have time to write my own Hough transform? But I'm going to give it a try to find arcs just using the circle formula and see.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at using [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)? It is an open-source C# wrapper of OpenCV. It also has a [shape detection sample](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp) you might interested in.

Comment: Thank you mevatron, I did saw this before I post this question, suppose I want to use this, but I need to download the EmguCV library right? That's my limitation for now, I cannot use their library. Yeah, I know it sucks, but I just have to come up with good methods myself to find those shapes.