# C# abstract shape detection

Tags: c#

I want to split different shapes from one bitmap into sepperate bitmaps. 
I have a working system that sorts colors.
 So i have a list of bitmaps with all sorts of shapes with one color.
 And i have a requirement: i do not want to use any kind of shape detection liberary.
Currently i only have a simple loop that loops trough all pixels in the bitmap and checks if there is a color to conclude that the pixel could be part of an old or new shape.

**variable-list**
layeredColorSystem = Bitmap
this is the result of the color sorting system.

```
foreach (Color colorLayer in layeredColorSystem.Keys)
            {
                Bitmap layer = layeredColorSystem[colorLayer];
                Bitmap shape = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height);
                for (int x = 0; x < layer.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < layer.Height; y++)
                    {
                        Color currentPixel = layer.GetPixel(x, y);
                        if (!currentPixel.Equals(colorLayer))
                        {
                            //no color here maybe a new shape can come up
                        } else
                        {
                            //color here maybe a part of an old shape maby a new shape.

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So my question is: how do i write a simple code that detects shapes and put each sepperate shape in a bitmap the same size of the origional bitmap? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no question!!!

Comment: @JeremyThompson The question is kind of obvious: How to put all the shapes from one bitmap into sepperate bitmaps.

Comment: The 2 close votes indicate its unclear what you're asking... in any case this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782338/search-for-shapes-in-bmp-image-file

Comment: @JeremyThompson changed it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm to find all the pixels within a particular patch of colour. Then, copy that information into the other bitmap. Once you've "moved" the pixels to other bitmap, keep track of which ones you have moved such that you do not re-process the same pixels.

If you want to determine the actual shape (e.g. is it a triangle? circle? etc), you will need to come up with rules, but basically, you need to extract each "object" from the image in order to be able to process it.

Other mechanisms may include edge detection, but it appears you are using change in colour as your "edges", which is a way of doing it.

Comment: I indeed use the change of colour. only it will not only paste the edges into the colour sorted bitmaps but also the inside of a shape.

Comment: using the flood-fill algorithm will copy the entire shape (including the "inside" pixels). If you just want to get the edges, run an edge detection algorithm against the resulting shape produced by flood-fill, and then you have just the edges. Neither approach will include pixels that are contained in a bounding box, but not in the shape.

Comment: Thank you for the reply this will work for sure! :)